# nsfetchedresultscontroller with empty sections

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a database of People and pets, with a one to many relationship

Person        Pet 
  Name          Name 
  Pet  <----->> Owner

I am using a UITableView backed by Core data and a nsfetchedresultscontroller to display the list of pets, grouped into sections by the owner.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityFromName:@"Pet"
    inManagedObjectContext:context]
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Owner.name"
    ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
    initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
    managedObjectContext:context
    sectionNameKeyPath:@"Owner.name"
    cacheName:@"Root"];
```

This works to display all pets under their owners section, however I also want to display the empty sections of People who do not have any pets? Is this possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Table views will not show empty sections by design.  This is a feature of the UITableView, not an issue with Core Data.

Comment: Yes they do... look at the ios calendar list view. If you have no appointments for today it lists and empty section.

Comment: That is an intentional override in one application.  UITableView, by design, will hide sections that are empty.

Comment: I think you are wrong, I am able to specify number of sections then for those sections numberOfRowsInSection return 0 rows and still have the title show.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I think what you intend to say is correct, but what you actually say is not, and this is why Bot is confused. `UITableView`'s definitely can show empty sections - by design too, which is why you can return 0 as the number of rows in a section, and that section still shows. But using a NSFetchedResultsController as the datasource will not allow you to show an empty section (at least that's what I think). Bot's example does not use NSFetchedResultsController, which is what the the OP was asking about

Comment: @Stretch agreed, I was confused on what he was saying. I thought he was saying UITableViews cannot show empty sections period.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with `NSFetchedResultsController`, however you can achieve what you are asking for by using an-almost substitute class `TAFetchedResultsController`.

See the info and get the code from here: https://github.com/timothyarmes/TAFetchedResultsController

Answer (score 0):

If there is only 1 section it's quite easy to bypass problem displaying header view of UITableView when there are no sections.